Can I create a multidimensional array containing a unit matrix without nested loops?
Suppose I have a Numpy array n indices, where the first n-2 represents some counting indices and the last 2 indices represent a square MxM matrix. I want to initialize this structure so it will contain copies of the unit matrix.
Example (here N=3, M=2):
A = numpy.zeros((3,2,2))
for k in range(3):
     A[k,:,:] = numpy.eye(2)

Another Example (here N=4, M=5):
B = numpy.zeros((3,4,5,5))
for k1 in range(3):
     for k2 in range(4):
         B[k1,k2,:,:] = numpy.eye(5)

Is there a way to do this without relying on nested loops?

You can repeat:
A = np.repeat(np.eye(2)[None], 3, axis=0)

For more complex cases, combined with reshape:
extra = (3, 4)
M = 5
B = np.repeat(np.eye(M)[None], np.prod(extra), axis=0).reshape(extra+(M, M))

Or with tile:
extra = (3, 4)
B = np.tile(np.eye(5), extra+(1, 1))

Or, from numpy.zeros using indexing:
B = np.zeros((3, 4, 5, 5))
x = np.arange(B.shape[-1])
B[..., x, x] = 1


"Compact" is not a very specific term, so it's hard to say what method would meet the requirement. However, one way would be to use numpy.tile, numpy.split, and numpy.stack, in that order. Use tile to get all your unit matrices arranged, split to break them into a list, then stack to put them into a single multi-dimensional array. Is this really more compact than a loop? Who knows, but you can do it in a single line.
You could also use a list comprehension, which doesn't eliminate the loop, but puts it in a single line.

By compact I mean a "one-liner" code. Moreover, I assume Numpy's built-in array functions are faster than carry out nested loops in Python.

One solution not mentioned yet is numpy.broadcast_to. Simple as:
numpy.broadcast_to(numpy.eye(2), shape=(3, 2, 2))

The broadcast_to() creates a read-only array. This is because it is a space-efficient view over the input array multiple times. If you need a writeable array just append a .copy()
